# How to properly call methods within a Rake task in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, task, rake

I'm starting with RoR, so I have a question about the implementation of rake tasks.

I have a rake file with a few lines that made some scheduled tasks with Twitter Gem Api.
Run the rake works properly, but I want to order my code.

Now the rake looks like this:

```
desc "This task is called by the scheduler"

task :update_feed => :environment do
  require 'twitter'

  client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
     #Client configs
  end

here.i.do.some.stuff

end
```

I'm pretty sure that have the client configs right there isn't a good idea.
On the other hand, I want to be able to save the methods within the model so I can use them elsewhere.

So, I'm trying to do this unsuccessfully:

```
#On tweet.rb model file:

class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
  validates :tweet_id, uniqueness: true
  
  def here_i_do_some_stuff
    #do some stuff
    #Plus config the client
  end

end

#And the rake file

task :update_feed => :environment do

  Tweet.here_i_do_some_stuff

end
```

And that's not working for

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `here_i_do_some_stuff' for Tweet (call 'Tweet.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

I don't really know how to do this, I tried other ways like write on other files and require them, but I think this is the correct way,  but I don't know how to make it run properly.

Thanks, JR.

Comment: Because you're calling it as a class method but it's an instance method. Try `Tweet.new.here_i_do_some_stuff` instead.

Comment: Ok! That works well! I spent more time writing the question than you in answers it. Thank you very much. Do you think this is the right way to get this done? As you can see, I'm fairly new with this.

Comment: You haven't really given a lot of context here about what you're trying to do but in general, yeah it looks fine. I would probably move `here_i_do_some_stuff` to the class method level `def self.fn_name` instead of `def fn_name` but that's a small detail.

Comment: Also, if this is _just_ a one-off task type of thing, maybe move it into its own class instead of tacking it onto `Tweet` class. But it's a personal preference thing.

Comment: Ok! That sounds good. Sorry for the lack of context. I don't want to put a bunch of code that doesn't make sense to the question. Actually, I want to do simply that, schedule some tasks with the Twitter gem and I want to do it in the best way possible. Thanks again.